# Blender crashes on baking (ambient occlusion)

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

Whenever the Blender Engine reaches 100% on 'Bake' for Ambient Occlusion, it crashes.
Is there any other way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Options are -

[image]

No Duplication

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, Although I've only Baked once, I notice you have the width and height of your texture map set at 4096, I would suggest maybe lowering that to 2048. According to Darrin lile's videos on Texturing, he encountered glitches when using a number that high.

Now if this is the same as your other textures you should probably scale them down too, just for the sake of them matching up. I could be totally wrong, but I'm just telling you what I think may work. I hope I'm helping here!

Comment: The maps don't have to match in size (although you might have to set up different UV coordinates for different sizes). As for lowering your AO map resolution, that would have been my advice, as well. +1